# Updating multiple columns using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write an SQL script where I can replace data in multiple columns, see below:

**SQL Script:**

```
UPDATE SohailsTest.dbo.OBJECT
SET VARIABLE = REPLACE(VARIABLE, 'C:\', 'E:\')
SET STATIC = REPLACE(STATIC, 'C:\', 'E:\');
```

I have tried the above, but it says:

**Error Message:**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>       Incorrect syntax near '='.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SET VARIABLE = REPLACE(VARIABLE, 'C:\', 'E:\'),
STATIC = REPLACE(STATIC, 'C:\', 'E:\');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use only one `SET`:

```
UPDATE SohailsTest.dbo.OBJECT
SET [VARIABLE] = REPLACE([VARIABLE], 'C:\', 'E:\'),
    [STATIC] = REPLACE([STATIC], 'C:\', 'E:\');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE SohailsTest.dbo.OBJECT
SET VARIABLE = REPLACE(VARIABLE, 'C:\', 'E:\'), STATIC = REPLACE(STATIC, 'C:\', 'E:\');
```